# How to change WordPress theme outside of admin? Can't access dashboard

Tags: themes, wp-admin, wp-config

I have extracted my theme via File Manager but it somehow crashed. I activated the theme and now I can not access my admin at /my-web/wp-admin/.

Is there another way to change my theme since I cannot access the admin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do.

**Option 1 - FTP**

Easiest would be to FTP into your site and change the name of the currently active theme.  Your themes are located in `\wp-content\themes\`.  Temporarily changing the name will disable the theme.  This should give you back access to the admin.

**Option 2 - Database / PhpMyAdmin**

You can also change the theme through the database, mostly likely via PhpMyAdmin.

There are 3 option rows in wp-options that you need to change.  Once you change these it will change your theme.

- template – the “Theme Name” as defined in style.css
- stylesheet – the actual name of your theme folder
- current_theme - the actual name of your theme folder

FYI - You can run the following SQL to narrow down just those 3 rows

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name = 'template'
OR option_name = 'stylesheet'
OR option_name = 'current_theme';
```